# Why didn't the piece of Voldemort’s soul in Harry come back to life with Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

I recently reread the books and found it curious that when Harry goes into the Forbidden Forest, and is killed by Voldemort but comes back to life, that the piece of soul in him doesn't come back with Harry. Because Harry never fully reached a state of death, he was just in King’s Cross which served sort of like a purgatory and the part of Voldemort's soul was also there under the bench, so why didn't it stay connected to Harry and come back to life?

Comment: Dunno if this is what's intended, but we could assume that what Harry sees when he's between life and death - the fragment of Voldemort's soul as its own independent entity - demonstrates that it's no longer connected to him. Perhaps Harry could've picked it up and taken it back with him, though of course he wouldn't want to

Comment: Yah but if it's its own entity then why cant it choose to go back to the living since Harry just leaves kings cross and comes back to life, or just attach itself to Harry?

Comment: If we assume that the King's Cross vision is an accurate metaphor for what's happening to their souls, then the condition of Voldemort's soul fragment would suggest that it can't "move" on its own - it's too weak, or too undeveloped as an independent being.

Comment: OK but IF that part of Voldemorts soul was a separate entity and IF it had enough energy could it get up, survive and live a half life like Voldemort did when the killing curse rebounded onto him? (this is mostly hypothetical now)

Comment: When a Horcrux is destroyed, the fragment of soul it contains is forever destroyed.  There doesn't seem to be any leeway there.  I see no reason to think that what happened to Harry is any different.

Comment: ... if, earlier on, a Dementor had sucked out Harry's soul, then the Voldemort-fragment might have been able to emerge and become a sort of shadow-Voldemort, like the Diary.  Or perhaps the Dementor might just have eaten the Voldemort-fragment too.  Not an experiment I'd be keen to try.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## It wasn’t tied to life by Lily’s sacrifice like Harry was.

Harry was kept alive by his blood (and therefore his mother’s sacrifice) being in the Dark Lord’s body, which tied the both of them to life.

> “He took your blood believing it would strengthen him. He took into his body a tiny part of the enchantment your mother laid upon you when she died for you. His body keeps her sacrifice alive, and while that enchantment survives, so do you and so does Voldemort’s one last hope for himself.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 35 (King’s Cross)*</sup></sub>

The piece of the Dark Lord’s soul in Harry didn’t have this blood tie, so when it was hit by the Killing Curse, it simply died and didn’t come back.

### The thing in King’s Cross wasn’t the soul in Harry - it was the main soul.

The piece of the Dark Lord’s soul that Harry sees in King’s Cross wasn’t the piece that had been in Harry - it was the main piece that returned to his body when he regained consciousness. J.K. Rowling said this clearly in the F.A.Q. of her website, and it was implied in the book as well.

> What exactly was the mutilated baby-like creature Harry saw at King's Cross in chapter 35 of 'Hallows'?
>
> I’ve been asked this a LOT. It is the last piece of soul Voldemort possesses. When Voldemort attacks Harry, they both fall temporarily unconscious, and both their souls - Harry's undamaged and healthy, Voldemort’s stunted and maimed - appear in the limbo where Harry meets Dumbledore. 
> <sub><sup>*[- F.A.Q. on J.K. Rowling’s website](http://web.archive.org/web/20080215132258/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=121)*</sup></sub>

This is why Dumbledore says Harry has less to fear from returning to King’s Cross - Harry will return whole, but the Dark Lord will return in that mutilated form.

> “But I know this, Harry, that you have less to fear from returning here than he does.’
>
> Harry glanced again at the raw-looking thing that trembled and choked in the shadow beneath the distant chair.”

It’s also why Harry told the Dark Lord he’s seen what he’ll become without remorse.

> “It’s your one last chance,’ said Harry, ‘it’s all you’ve got left … I’ve seen what you’ll be otherwise … be a man … try … try for some remorse …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

That specific piece of soul in King’s Cross did return to life - just in the Dark Lord, not in Harry.

Comment: Ok this makes a lot of sense, thanks but im going to wait for a while to see if any more interesting perspectives pop up

Comment: @padfoot Thanks, I’m glad you liked it! :) I tried to answer the part about the piece of soul Harry sees in King’s Cross as well as the part about the piece of soul in Harry, since they’re different pieces but both mentioned in your question.

Comment: yeah! i really appreciate your in depth explanation and all your quotes that back it up!

Comment: @padfoot Thanks so much! :) I worked hard on it, and I’m happy that you appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is because that part is what the wand killed. But Harry had a choice to go back because the wand wasn't going to kill it's true master.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! This appears to be speculation and as a Q/A site we require something a bit more substantial. Can you [edit] to add any evidence to back up your answer? Also don't forget to take the [tour]!